# Springboot security+jwt 'springSecurityFilterChain' error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I got some error on my springboot code. 
But i'm not able to know why that is having error and not working.

I used Jpa. and that was working well
(as on clearly before using security and Oauth,jwt)
i added filter to @Configuration.

logs are on here

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(Lorg/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at kr.avansoft.demo.TokenServerTestV3Application.main(TokenServerTestV3Application.java:20)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(Lorg/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(Lorg/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder;)V
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer.passwordEncoder(AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer.java:72)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$DefaultPasswordEncoderAuthenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:573)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.init(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.init(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:292)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2e1380d3.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$3(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2e1380d3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4dfe46c7.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2e1380d3.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

---

my SecurityConfig file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= {"kr.avansoft.bean.repository"})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(shaPasswordEncoder);
        return provider; 
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(name=BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    public 

    @Autowired
    SHAPasswordEncoder shaPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailService;

    @Autowired
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider; 

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and().formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
        .failureUrl("/login")
        .and()
        .logout();
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= {"kr.avansoft.bean.repository"})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(shaPasswordEncoder);
        return provider; 
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(name=BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    public 

    @Autowired
    SHAPasswordEncoder shaPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailService;

    @Autowired
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider; 

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and().formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
        .failureUrl("/login")
        .and()
        .logout();
    }

}
```

---

AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter are..

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= {"kr.avansoft.bean.repository"})
public class AuthConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    SHAPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to assign the password encoder to DaoAuthenticationProvider. In fact you  shouldn't need a DaoAuthenticationProvider at all.

You can set both userDetailsService and passwordEncoder in the SecurityConfig bean:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
          .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
          .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    } 

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); // or any other compatible encoder 
        return encoder;
    }
}
```

One more **important** detail; unless required specifically due to your circumstances, you shouldn't use SHA for password encoding. Discussed in length [here](https://rietta.com/blog/2016/02/05/bcrypt-not-sha-for-passwords/) and [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/133239/what-is-the-specific-reason-to-prefer-bcrypt-or-pbkdf2-over-sha256-crypt-in-pass)

Comment: Thanks for your help. So, I got next Error XD

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that the spring-security-core version is the same version as the spring-core or web or spring-boot(cross check with the maven repo). At least in my case, that's how I resolved the issue. There was a mismatch in the dependency versions, which caused the dependencies to clash.